# mutate to transforma field of text into wrapped strings

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

```
adf <- data.frame(
      s = c('jfgjksdfg ikbhsjfkv jhdjkfvb kjhgjkhjbhk jhfjdf khkhk',
            'kjhgf kjhg hgdhjksmn',
            'cats dogs'),
      n = 1:3)

adf
                                                      s n
1 jfgjksdfg ikbhsjfkv jhdjkfvb kjhgjkhjbhk jhfjdf khkhk 1
2                                  kjhgf kjhg hgdhjksmn 2
3                                             cats dogs 3
```

I'd like to wrap each of the 3 rows of text in s to be 10 wide. Tried:

```
library(stringr)

    adf %>% mutate(blah = cat(str_wrap(s, width = 10), "\n")) %>% glimpse
    jfgjksdfg
    ikbhsjfkv
    jhdjkfvb
    kjhgjkhjbhk
    jhfjdf
    khkhk kjhgf kjhg
    hgdhjksmn cats dogs 
    Rows: 3
    Columns: 2
    $ s <chr> "jfgjksdfg ikbhsjfkv jhdjkfvb kjhgjkhjbhk jhfjdf khkhk", "kjhgf kjhg hgdhjksmn", "cats dogs"
    $ n <int> 1, 2, 3
```

Not sure what this is, but I was expecting a new field blah that is just wrapped text version of s on the same 3 rows. How can I do this?

[Edit]
Screen shot showing desired outcome. I had to guess what width=10 looks like on a spreadsheet
[image]

Comment: But, if you do with `width = 10`, it would be completed with the first word itself

Comment: For the last row, you are splitting 'cats' and 'dogs' into two, while in the first row and second row, the width is different for splitting.  The logic for desired outcome is not so clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may change the `width` to a larger value as width = 10, will create the wrapping around the first word itself in the first row of 's'

```
substr(adf$s, 1, 10)
[1] "jfgjksdfg " "kjhgf kjhg" "cats dogs"
```

According to `?str_wrap`

> width - positive integer giving target line width in **characters**. A width less than or equal to 1 will put each word on its own line.

Also, `cat` is used to print the output and there is no `return` value.  We can remove the `cat` wrapping and use the below code directly in `DT::datatable`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
adf %>%
     mutate(s = str_wrap(s, width = 20))
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, this results in a df with 9 rows. Desired result is the same number of rows, just that the text displayed within each cell is wrapped.

Comment: It's to eventually get passed to DT::datatable, this is just a cosmetic thing

Comment: @DougFir why not just use `str_wrap` and leave it that way.

Comment: I'm testing that just now but whent he output is displayed by DT::datatable(), the full strings appear in this case, as if I never wrapped them at all :/

Comment: The width specified is 10.  I am not sure how you are expecting the output

Comment: OK, the first string which is pretty long. I'd like it to still display within a single cell, but for the text to wrap. So rather than just a horizontal row of `jfgjksdfg ikbhsjfkv jhdjkfvb kjhgjkhjbhk jhfjdf khkhk` the same cell would wrap. I cannot get the comment markup to show as I want. I could display in in a spreadsheet and take  a screen shot if it's still unclear?

Comment: Can you show in the post how it should look as expected

Comment: See screen shot I just added. Does it make sense?

Comment: @DougFir with `width = 10`, it is only wrapping at each word.  You may need to increase the width i.e. `adf %>%
      mutate(s = cat(str_wrap(s, width = 20), sep="\n"))`

Comment: This returns a 1 col df! Was expecting two cols, the newly wrapped s and then n?

Comment: @DougFir That is only because I wrapped with `cat`.  If you are using this on DT, you may directly use it